# Derivative equal to zero at a point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Currently playing around with functions that involve $\sin(\frac{1}{x}).$ And a question came up. Is there any function, which's derivative at a point is equal to $0,$ but this point is not local extrema or point of inflection?

Comment: Would Devil's staircase help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: Ok, this one works, but are there any "nice" elementary functions with that property?

Comment: $f(x)=0$, perhaps?

Comment: I think it has an extrema everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x},$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the value of the floor function at $x.$